# Drawing a Continuous Line with a Mouse with wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, radio-button, wxpython

I am trying to make a "whiteboard" application in wxPython.  I am trying to figure out how to draw a line that follows the mouse when the user is clicking down.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="White Board")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDrag)

def OnDrag(self, e):
    print "drag"
```

The first step is trying to get the mouse coordinates while the user is dragging the mouse, but I am unable to get the word "drag" to print no matter what I do and don't understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse event, [`wx.EVT_MOTION`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MouseEvent.html), will give you continuous updates as the mouse moves.  Then determine whether the button is down, and also get the X and Y positions, using, say, [wx.MouseState](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MouseState.html).

`wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG` won't work because: 1) it's a list control event; 2) it only fires when you **begin** to drag, not the entire time.